# Menu Heading in Dynamic/Mobile menu

Tags: html, css

Ok, so put simply, I've recently incorporated a drop down menu to one of my navigation links, you click the nav option and the menu drops drown, no problems, but when you look at the site on a mobile device, although the menu options are there, the heading isn't..

My normal nav menu is as follows:

> ***Home   About   Products  
>   Bullion   Contacts***

With ***products*** being the drop down part.

this is what i currently get in the mobile menu,

> Home
>  About
>  Home 1
>  Home 2
>  Home 3
>  Home 4
>   Bullion
>  Contacts

and this is what i want it to look like

> Home
>  About
>  Products
>    Home 1
>      Home 2
>     Home 3
>     Home 4
>   Bullion
>  Contacts

You with me so far? i hope so,
Now here is the mobile css for the nav menu;

```
 /* Mobile UI */

#mobileUI-site-titlebar {
    background: url('images/headerM.png') 0px -35px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 15px 30px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

#mobileUI-site-title {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    line-height: 51px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#mobileUI-site-nav-opener {
    width: 50px;
    background: url('images/mobileUI-site-nav-opener-bg.svg') 

center center no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#mobileUI-site-nav-opener:active {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#mobileUI-site-nav {
    background: #1e1e1e top left repeat-x;
    box-shadow: inset -5px 0px 60px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

#mobileUI-site-nav-inner {
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
}

.mobileUI-site-nav-link {
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
}
```

And here is the html for the nav menu..

```
  <nav class="mobileUI-site-nav" id="site-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Homepage</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>

                        </li>

                         <li class="headLink">Products
                                <ul id"cssdropdown">
                                    <li><a href="#">Home1</a>

                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Home4</a>

                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Home2</a>

                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Home3</a>

                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Home5</a>

                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bullion</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
```

Hopefully this will make it a little clearer.. here is my desktop nav..
[image]

and here is the mobile nav..
[image]

I know alignment is out, but for now i just want the mobile element fixed..

So basically, I want the heading ***Products*** to appear in the mobile navigation menu. I thought it would be there automatically, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.
Any help will be gratefully received!

Lee

Comment: i think the code is incomplete... http://jsfiddle.net/ZrDmv/

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SaurabhLP , Which code? your fiddle shows what it should look like, but when in use on my site, and the browser is shrunk down for the mobile menu, the Products heading disappears. my guess is its something to do with the headlink class being nested inside the mobile-site-nav class.. but I dont know how to get around that. i cant remove the headlink class as it is needed for desktop browsing. does that make sense?

Comment: i didnt see any style to it, is it a dropdown? from the code i dont see anything but problem with ids and classes make sure you defined them correctly...

Comment: its a drop down when viewed on a desktop, but then i just want the links nested like your fiddle shows for mobile device
the headlink class and cssdropdown id is relating to the drop down, would seeing the css for the desktop drop down element help? @SaurabhLP

Answer (score 0):

From your code i can only figure out that you want the #cssdropdown to be in left... Just add this css code to your css...

**CSS:-**

```
#cssdropdown { margin-left:5px; } //Increase it as your wish
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didnt see that make any difference, however, I have added some images to my first post, hopefully that will explain what I want a little better. Thanks again.